Recreating exactly the same ball, HTML5 to SpriteKit
I have the following SCSS code to define a ball I have in a game:
$color-green-dark: #226f54;

$color-cream: #f4f0bb;
$color-coffee: #7b4b39;
$color-brown: #43291f;

.ballType1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  &::after {
    content: '';
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #00000030;

    background-image: radial-gradient(
      circle at 40% 40%,
      mix($color-cream, $color-coffee, 90%) 5%,
      mix($color-cream, $color-coffee, 40%) 50%,
      mix($color-cream, $color-brown, 10%) 80%
    );
  }
}

It renders to what I want:

I tried to recreate the same ball with SpriteKit, but it's not what I wanted:

The code I ended up with is (GameScene):
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        
        // Setup your scene initial state here
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.greenDark
        
        addBall()
    }
    
    func addBall() {
        let ballRadius = 100.0
        let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 70)
        
        let shader = SKShader(source: """
            void main() {
                float dist = distance(v_tex_coord, vec2(0.4, 0.4));
                vec3 color = mix(vec3(0.957, 0.941, 0.733), vec3(0.482, 0.294, 0.224), smoothstep(0.05, 0.5, dist));
                color = mix(color, vec3(0.259, 0.161, 0.122), smoothstep(0.5, 0.8, dist));
                gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
            }
        """)
        
        ball.fillShader = shader
        ball.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
        
        let shadowNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
        shadowNode.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.19)
        shadowNode.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
        shadowNode.position = CGPoint(x: 2, y: -2)
        shadowNode.zPosition = -1
        
        let shadowBlurNode = SKEffectNode()
        shadowBlurNode.shouldRasterize = true
        shadowBlurNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", parameters: ["inputRadius": 5])
        shadowBlurNode.addChild(shadowNode)
        
        ball.addChild(shadowBlurNode)
        
        addChild(ball)
    }

Things are getting really messy when you change the radius to 20. It doesn't look nice.
I'm looking for ways to render it nicely, what are my options? I'm leaning towards creating SVG, and importing it somehow. I'm not very good at shaders, tried multiple parameters without too much luck.
Maybe I am missing something obvious? How do I recreate the same ball from HTML/CSS?
I tried to recreate things manually with shaders. Editing shaders, but it's only getting messier.

I get this result with the code below:

func addBall() {
    let ballRadius = 100.0
    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
    
    let shader = SKShader(source: """
        void main() {
            float dist = distance(v_tex_coord, vec2(0.4, 0.6)); // I changed this. Just a preference.
            vec3 colorCream = vec3(0.957, 0.941, 0.733);
            vec3 colorCoffee = vec3(0.482, 0.294, 0.224);
            vec3 colorBrown = vec3(0.263, 0.161, 0.122);
            vec3 mixedColor1 = mix(colorCream, colorCoffee, 0.1);  // 90% cream, 10% coffee
            vec3 mixedColor2 = mix(colorCream, colorCoffee, 0.6);  // 40% cream, 60% coffee
            vec3 mixedColor3 = mix(colorCream, colorBrown, 0.9);  // 10% cream, 90% brown
            vec3 color = mix(mixedColor1, mixedColor2, smoothstep(0.05, 0.5, dist));
            color = mix(color, mixedColor3, smoothstep(0.5, 0.8, dist));
            gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
        }
    """)
    
    ball.fillShader = shader
    ball.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
    
    let shadowNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius + 5) // edited
    shadowNode.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.15) // edited
    shadowNode.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
    shadowNode.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: -10) // edited
    
    let shadowBlurNode = SKEffectNode()
    shadowBlurNode.zPosition = -1 // this is the main change
    shadowBlurNode.shouldRasterize = true
    shadowBlurNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", parameters: ["inputRadius": 35]) // edited
    shadowBlurNode.addChild(shadowNode)
    
    ball.addChild(shadowBlurNode)
    
    addChild(ball)
}

I changed the first line of the shader (to move the highlight a bit up) and used shadowBlurNode.zPosition = -1 instead of shadowNode.zPosition = -1. Is that closer to your goal?
Edit: I uploaded a new image with a tweaked shadow. Playing around with the shadow node.

Turns out my color conversion was incorrect. I got this in the end:

Not perfect, but still something. Here is the updated code:
    func addBall() {
        let ballRadius = 100.0
        let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)  // Centering the ball at the middle of the screen

        let shader = SKShader(source: """
            void main() {
                float dist = distance(v_tex_coord, vec2(0.4, 0.4)); // Adjust center to 40%, 40%
                vec3 colorCream = vec3(0.957, 0.941, 0.733);
                vec3 colorCoffee = vec3(0.482, 0.294, 0.224);
                vec3 colorBrown = vec3(0.263, 0.161, 0.122);
                vec3 mixedColor1 = mix(colorCream, colorCoffee, 0.1);  // 90% cream, 10% coffee
                vec3 mixedColor2 = mix(colorCream, colorCoffee, 0.6);  // 40% cream, 60% coffee
                vec3 mixedColor3 = mix(colorCream, colorBrown, 0.9);  // 10% cream, 90% brown
                vec3 color = mix(mixedColor1, mixedColor2, smoothstep(0.05, 0.5, dist));
                color = mix(color, mixedColor3, smoothstep(0.5, 0.8, dist));
                gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
            }
        """)

        ball.fillShader = shader
        ball.strokeColor = SKColor.clear

        let shadowNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
        shadowNode.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.19)
        shadowNode.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
        shadowNode.position = CGPoint(x: 2, y: -2)
        shadowNode.zPosition = -1

        let shadowBlurNode = SKEffectNode()
        shadowBlurNode.shouldRasterize = true
        shadowBlurNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", parameters: ["inputRadius": 5])
        shadowBlurNode.addChild(shadowNode)

        ball.addChild(shadowBlurNode)

        addChild(ball)
    }

I still have some artifacts I want to fix. Since the ball in HTML looks a bit better, so good so you wanna kiss it:

I don't know why. Still looking for answers how to reproduce it 100%.
